# Is this a context-free language?

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

Let $L = L_1^* \circ L_2^*$  where $L_1 = \{1^n 0^m 1^n : n,m \in \Bbb N\}$ and $L_2 = \{0^m 1^{2m} : m \in N\}$.

Is the language $L$ a context free language?

I think I can write automata for $L_1$ and $L_2$ but can't really find a way to add the $^*$ and to concatenate together.

Comment: I formatted your question. Please make sure I did so correctly.

Comment: Please show what automata you can write. Also, please explain what the $*$ means.

Comment: @dfeuer I'd assume that's the Kleene Star?

Comment: Yes, $L$ is conext free, since $L_1$ ans $L_2$ are context free and context free languages are closed under concatenation and star. Does that answer your question, or are you asking how to construct a push down automaton for it?

Comment: Yes it's the Kleene star and yes it answer my question. Thanks a lot. If I really can't draw it, I will post where I'm stuck in this post!